how to use the terminal in opendevin?
export WORKSPACE_BASE=$(pwd)/workspace;

docker run \
    --pull=always \
    -e SANDBOX_USER_ID=$(id -u) \
    -e WORKSPACE_MOUNT_PATH=$WORKSPACE_BASE \
    -v $WORKSPACE_BASE:/opt/workspace_base \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
    ghcr.io/opendevin/opendevin:0.5


why is the terminal read-only?
At first, I thought it was a bug but then I saw it also on a screenshot from the GitHub page. is this normal?

I also can't execute files or use the browser, it seems like only the agent can use the terminal and execute code

Probably a question for opendevin's issues page!

Now, OpenDevin supports writable terminal.
